# Algorithm equation, several parts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Consider the following algorithm:

Procedure (n: integer)

```
 A:=0
 i:=0
 While i<=n
   j:=i
   While j<=n
     A:= A+1
     j:= j+1
   Endwhile
 i:=i+1
 Endwhile
 Print A
```

> a) Use words to describe the output A in terms of the input n.
>
> b) For a given input n, carefully count the number of elementary
>   operations used by this algorithm.

$$3(n) + 3(n-1) + 3(n-2)+ ... +３(n-(n-2)) + 3(n-(n-1)) + 3(n-n) + 1
3(n)+3(n-1)+3(n-2)+...+3(2)+3(1)+3(0)+1
3[n+(n-1)+(n+2)+...2+1+0]+1
3[n(n+1)/2] = 3n(n+1)/2 = (3n^2+3n+1)/2$$

outer loop two operations doing it n time $2(n)+1$ choosing for last comparison

total is:
$(3n^2+3n+1)/2 +2n+1$

> c) Suppose n is large. What happens to the running time for this
>   algorithm when n is doubled?

$n^2$ -> $4n^2$ the time will be 4 times longer

I actually got 0/20 on the problem for a test, I was wondering if anyone could try to help me solve the problem.

Comment: Your post seems to emphasize (part a) an inability to read the code with understanding of its procedure.  This is not closely related to any mathematical concepts other than counting.  As it stands it could well be closed as off-topic, esp. given its "several parts".  Possibly it would better resemble an on-topic question if you worked out the issue with part a, and then suggested why you might have gotten no points on the other two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For an input $n$, the algorithm outputs
   $$\sum_{i=0}^n(n-i) = \sum_{k=0}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
2. At each step $i$ you have $1$ comparison (line 3) and one other operation (line 9), then for each $j$ you have again one comparison and two other operations (the nested while loop). This should give
   $$2n + \sum_{i=0}^n3(n-i) = 2n + 3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
   operations.
3. The complexity is of course $O(n^2)$, so for large enough input doubling $n$ makes the running time become approximately $4$ times larger.

Comment: Why is doubling O(n^2) make it 4n^2? That doesn't make sense to me. Is it because n is 2, so n^2 is 4? so total is 4n^2? We didn't really learn big-O notation. Should I think of the way you express O(n^2) similar to a function f(x)? So if the exponential O(n^2) is 'doubled', then the result is a run time of O((2)^2), making it equal to 4? So the entire O(n^2) becomes roughly 4 times as long in duration?

Comment: @JaredY No, you got it wrong. Say the complexity function of the algorithm is $f(n)$. Informally, saying that $f$ is $O(n^2)$ means that for $n\gg0$ we have $f(n)\approx Cn^2$ for some constant $C$. Therefore, always for $n$ big, $f(2n) \approx C(2n)^2 = 4(Cn^2)\approx 4f(n)$.